# Reversing Assembly to C

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c, x86-64

I've read the open letter addressing students asking for help with their homework and I agree with it, therefore I will try to be less of a pain in the *** ;)
I need to reverse the x86-64 (AT&T) assembly back to C (fill in the blanks). I did most of the task, except a few things I didn't understand.
Here is the assembly code (the compiler did some optimizations such as making the first function inline):

```
0000000000401c50 <checkPasswordAux>:
401c50: 48 8d 77 11             lea    0x11(%rdi),%rsi
401c54: 31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
401c56: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401c5d: 00 00 00 
401c60: 0f b6 17                movzbl (%rdi),%edx
401c63: 84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
401c65: 74 29                   je     401c90 <checkPasswordAux+0x40>
401c67: 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401c6e: 00 00 
401c70: 89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
401c72: 83 e1 01                and    $0x1,%ecx
401c75: 01 c8                   add    %ecx,%eax
401c77: d0 fa                   sar    %dl
401c79: 75 f5                   jne    401c70 <checkPasswordAux+0x20>
401c7b: 48 83 c7 01             add    $0x1,%rdi
401c7f: 48 39 fe                cmp    %rdi,%rsi
401c82: 75 dc                   jne    401c60 <checkPasswordAux+0x10>
401c84: b8 64 00 00 00          mov    $0x64,%eax
401c89: c3                      retq   
401c8a: 66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401c90: f3 c3                   repz retq 
401c92: 0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
401c96: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401c9d: 00 00 00 

0000000000401ca0 <checkPassword>:
401ca0: 4c 8d 47 11             lea    0x11(%rdi),%r8
401ca4: 48 89 fe                mov    %rdi,%rsi
401ca7: 31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
401ca9: 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
401cb0: 0f b6 06                movzbl (%rsi),%eax
401cb3: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
401cb5: 74 29                   je     401ce0 <checkPassword+0x40>
401cb7: 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401cbe: 00 00 
401cc0: 89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
401cc2: 83 e1 01                and    $0x1,%ecx
401cc5: 01 ca                   add    %ecx,%edx
401cc7: d0 f8                   sar    %al
401cc9: 75 f5                   jne    401cc0 <checkPassword+0x20>
401ccb: 48 83 c6 01             add    $0x1,%rsi
401ccf: 4c 39 c6                cmp    %r8,%rsi
401cd2: 75 dc                   jne    401cb0 <checkPassword+0x10>
401cd4: 31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
401cd6: c3                      retq   
401cd7: 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401cde: 00 00 
401ce0: 83 fa 19                cmp    $0x19,%edx
401ce3: 7f ef                   jg     401cd4 <checkPassword+0x34>
401ce5: 0f be 07                movsbl (%rdi),%eax
401ce8: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
401cea: 74 4e                   je     401d3a <checkPassword+0x9a>
401cec: 83 e8 61                sub    $0x61,%eax
401cef: 48 98                   cltq   
401cf1: 48 83 f8 19             cmp    $0x19,%rax
401cf5: 77 dd                   ja     401cd4 <checkPassword+0x34>
401cf7: 31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
401cf9: eb 1b                   jmp    401d16 <checkPassword+0x76>
401cfb: 0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
401d00: 83 e8 61                sub    $0x61,%eax
401d03: 48 98                   cltq   
401d05: 48 83 f8 19             cmp    $0x19,%rax
401d09: 77 c9                   ja     401cd4 <checkPassword+0x34>
401d0b: 48 89 c1                mov    %rax,%rcx
401d0e: 48 f7 d1                not    %rcx
401d11: 48 39 d1                cmp    %rdx,%rcx
401d14: 72 be                   jb     401cd4 <checkPassword+0x34>
401d16: 48 8d 0c 52             lea    (%rdx,%rdx,2),%rcx
401d1a: 48 83 c7 01             add    $0x1,%rdi
401d1e: 48 8d 14 8a             lea    (%rdx,%rcx,4),%rdx
401d22: 48 8d 14 50             lea    (%rax,%rdx,2),%rdx
401d26: 0f be 07                movsbl (%rdi),%eax
401d29: 84 c0                   test   %al,%al
401d2b: 75 d3                   jne    401d00 <checkPassword+0x60>
401d2d: 31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
401d2f: 48 39 15 0a 13 20 00    cmp    %rdx,0x20130a(%rip)        # 603040 <hash>
401d36: 0f 94 c0                sete   %al
401d39: c3                      retq   
401d3a: 31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
401d3c: eb ef                   jmp    401d2d <checkPassword+0x8d>
401d3e: 66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

And here is the C code (with the things I filled):

```
int checkPasswordAux(char* s) {
    int sum = __0__;
    while(__*s__) {
        char c = *s;
        if(c-'a' > 25) {
            return 100;
        }
        while(c) {
            sum += c __%2__;
            c __>>=__ 1;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return sum;
}
bool checkPassword(char* s) {
    char* copy = s;
    if(checkPasswordAux(s) > __25__) {
        return 0;
    }
    s = copy;
    unsigned long y = 0;
    while(__*s__) {
        unsigned long x = *s - __97__;
        if(x > __25__) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(y > ____) {
            return 0;
        }
        y = __x+13y__;
        s++;
    }
    return __y==0x939f103__;
}
```

Basically the only thing missing is the 'if' condition in the second function. I can't really find this condition in the assembly.
Another thing is, in the previous questions I find that the value of the  variable is 0x939f103.
Again, sorry for being a needy student, any help will be very much appreciated <3

Comment: First of all, I found a mistake, it should be "y = x + 26y".
Second thing is I think the if condition is "y > ~x" - y is bigger than not x.